# Shuffle a column between rows

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I shuffle the contents of a large (1m to 5m record) table efficiently? The column is known to have unique values, but you can assume that all constraints are removed for the purposes of this. My headaches are primarily because I am updating the same column I am selecting from. My goal is to do this with PL/SQL so that I can take additional action programmatically such as logging or updating other tables.

```
**Original table:**
+----+-----------+
| id | fname     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | mike      |
|  2 | ricky     |
|  3 | jane      |
|  4 | august    |
|  6 | dave      |
|  9 | Jérôme    |
+----+-----------+

**Possible output:**
+----+-----------+
| id | fname     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | dave      |
|  2 | jane      |
|  3 | mike      |
|  4 | ricky     |
|  6 | Jérôme    |
|  9 | august    |
+----+-----------+
```

My latest attempts have been to create a cursor that uses `over (order by dbms_random.value)` and to try to do a merge or update perhaps based on rownum. Perhaps I can get around the modifying self constraint by creating a temp table of sorts? I'm fairly confident Oracle has some fancy way to do this but I am limited in my SQL abilities to the basic CRUD commands.

The full solution is here, based on Gordon's answer:

```
merge into t
using (
select t.id, t2.name
from (select t.*, rownum as seqnum
      from t
     ) t join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t2
     on t.seqnum = t2.seqnum
) src
on (t.id = src.id)
when matched then update set t.name = src.name;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a self join, using random row numbers:

```
select t.id, t2.name
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t2
     on t.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Actually, you don't need for both to be randomized:

```
select t.id, t2.name
from (select t.*, rownum as seqnum
      from t
     ) t join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t2
     on t.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, one quibble I have is that the t1 should just be t. Anyway, how would I get an update from this? Would I need to generate a merge statement based on this query?

Comment: I was able to get it to work with merge, thanks again. I'll post the full solution in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Taken directly from this answer (it was mine, so I believe I am allowed to reuse it): 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3995265

**Preparation**

```
create table original_table ( id number, name varchar2(30) );

insert into original_table
  select 1, 'mike'   from dual union all
  select 2, 'ricky'  from dual union all
  select 3, 'jane'   from dual union all
  select 4, 'august' from dual union all
  select 6, 'dave'   from dual union all
  select 9, 'Jérôme' from dual
;

select * from original_table;

ID  NAME
--  ------
1   mike
2   ricky
3   jane
4   august
6   dave
9   Jérôme
```

Updating the rows with permuted names:

```
merge into original_table o
  using (
    with
         helper ( id, rn, rand_rn ) as (
           select id,
                  row_number() over (order by id),
                  row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value())
           from   original_table
         )
    select ot.name, h2.id
    from   original_table ot inner join helper h1 on      ot.id = h1.id
                             inner join helper h2 on h1.rand_rn = h2.rn
  ) p
on (o.id = p.id)
when matched then update set o.name = p.name
;

select * from original_table;

ID  NAME
--  ------
1   ricky
2   dave
3   Jérôme
4   jane
6   august
9   mike
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I have the same problem but I need to guarantee the gender of each names: male, female and unknown. How can I apply this condition to this solutions? Any thoughts?

Comment: @milheiros - Do you have a separate column for gender, or do you need to guess it from the name?