# Shuffle a column between rows and update

Tags: sql, oracle

For test purpose, I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE DANILO.TESTE2(
CPF VARCHAR2(11),
NOME VARCHAR2(100));

insert into danilo.teste2 values ('93434433443','Sousa');
insert into danilo.teste2 values ('54545454545','Ferreira');
insert into danilo.teste2 values ('99393201832','Cavalcante');
insert into danilo.teste2 values ('13902939392','Silva');
```

Then, I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008985/shuffle-a-column-between-rows) to Shuffle `cpf` column data, and it's working fine for my case.

```
select t2.cpf, t.nome
from (select t.*, rownum as seqnum from danilo.teste2 t) t join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum from danilo.teste2 t) t2 -- TABELA QUE EMBARALHA
     on t.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

But how can I shuffling it and update all cpf rows?

I've tried something like it:

```
     MERGE INTO danilo.teste2 t1
USING (
    SELECT 
        cpf,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) AS random_order
    FROM danilo.teste2
) shuffled_data
ON (1 = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.cpf = shuffled_data.cpf;
```

but I got `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables`

What I need is to Shuffle `cpf` column data to "mask" it, but leaving the real data.

Comment: Is `nome` a key or guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: No, nome isn't a key or unique

Comment: Are both columns together unique? The problem with your existing query is that `1=1` matches every row in `teste2` with every row in `shuffled_date`, so you'll want a way to match each row to exactly one replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your query (or something similar correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column) in the `USING` clause of a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO danilo.teste2 dst
USING (
  select t.rid,
         t2.nome
  from   (
           SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
                  ROWID AS rid
           FROM   danilo.teste2
         ) t
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT nome,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) AS rn
           FROM   danilo.teste2
         ) t2
         ON t.rn = t2.rn
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET nome = src.nome;
```

Then, after the `MERGE` statement, the table may (randomly) contain:

| CPF | NOME |
| --- | --- |
| 93434433443 | Cavalcante |
| 54545454545 | Sousa |
| 99393201832 | Ferreira |
| 13902939392 | Silva |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Oab55h70)

Comment: Thank you for your help! It worked perfectly! May I ask why it works even when the table has foreign keys? let's say nome is a pk and it has a fk in another table, usually, to update the parent table, we need to update the child table field first. However, with the merge command, does it happen automatically? In my tests, I didn't need to update child field; they were automatically updated with the merge. Edit: This automatic update in the child fields is great for me as well. I'm just trying to understand why this happens.